# Which component should i use?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, controls, postback, client-side

I am using the `<a>` element to increase the font size in my webpage.

```
<a href="javascript:increaseFontSize();">+</a>
```

The problem with it is that i cannot set a background image.

So what component should i choose from the VS2008 toolbox that has OnClientClick property and does not post-back?

For examaple, i set the OnClientClick property in a ImageButton, but the postback is executed after the ClientSide click

Comment: What is it exactly you need accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you want to use server controls? Can't you give a class to the anchor and define a background image:

```
<a href="javascript:increaseFontSize();" class="plus">+</a>
```

And in css:

```
.plus {
    background-image:url('plus.gif');
}
```

Comment: I did not want to use a server side control. I am just a newbie!

Answer (score 1):

The element has to be a block element to be able to have a background image. You shouldn't use a link anyway, as it's not really a link to anywhere.

It doesn't have to be a server control out of the toolbox, server controls tend to have extra code added to them to do postbacks. You can simply use a div element and style it to look any way you want. For example:

HTML:

```
<div class="increase" onclick="increaseFontSize();">+</div>
```

CSS:

```
.increase { width: 20px; height: 20px; background: url(button.gif); color: #ccc; }
.increase:hover { color: #fff; }
```